# how to install any android emulator without admin right?

Tags: windows, admin, emulation

I am looking for any android emulator to run on my work laptop it is windows 10 and cannot be upgraded to windows 11 so i need alternative to android apps application which i can run wohtout admin rights

I tried bluesacks ,nox player ,ld  player

Answer (score 0):

try downloading qemu and extracting the setup with 7zip (winrar doesnt work for some reason)